# Chef-client service (12.2.1) doesn't run on Ubuntu 14.04 after being successfully installed and started

Tags: chef-infra, ubuntu-14.04

I installed chef-client to run as a service. It started successfully and show up in 'ps aux' running under 'root' but it never produced anything other than this in the log although there is a long run-list associated with that node

```
[2015-08-17T10:15:50+00:00] INFO: Forked, in 1928. Privileges: 0 0
[2015-08-17T12:13:27+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
```

On the other hand, running "chef-client --once" with the setting settings (client.rb) produces expected result and lots of records in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it's a [new and intended behavior](https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/3791) of Chef 12. The previous versions of Chef Client service immediately initiated the client run after it gets started.